# Having an issue using pipes to send string from two children processes to their parent process

Tags: c

I am trying to learn piping to for interprocess communication. My code creates 2 children processes from the main parent process and I am trying to use pipe to send a string from both children to the parent. It seems the first child's string is being sent correctly, but the second child's string is not. My program is as follows:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int pdes0[2];
    int pdes1[2];
    pipe(pdes0);
    pipe(pdes1);
    if(pdes0 < 0)
    {
        printf("Error creating pipe pdes0\n");
    }
    if(pdes1 < 0)
    {
        printf("Error creating pipe pdes1\n");
    }
    printf("Parent pid: %d\n", getpid());
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            /* child */
            if(i == 0)
            {
                /* child 0 */
                printf("Child0 pid %d from parent pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                char child0[10] = "child0";
                printf("Child0: %s\n", child0);
                close(pdes0[0]);
                write(pdes0[1], child0, strlen(child0)+1);
             }
            if(i == 1)
            {
                /* child 1 */
                printf("Child1 pid %d from parent pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                char child1[10] = "child1";
                printf("Child1: %s\n", child1);
                close(pdes1[0]);
                write(pdes1[1], child1, strlen(child1)+1);
            }
            exit(0);
            }
        else
        {
            /* parent */
            char inbuf0[10];
            char inbuf1[10];
            close(pdes0[1]);
            read(pdes0[0], inbuf0, 10);
            printf("Parent0 read: %s\n", inbuf0);
            close(pdes0[0]);

            close(pdes1[1]);
            read(pdes1[0], inbuf1, 10);
            printf("Parent1 read: %s\n", inbuf1);
            close(pdes1[0]);
         }

    }
    wait(NULL);
}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
Parent pid: 3181 
Child0 pid 3182 from parent pid 3181 
Child0: child0
Parent0 read: child0
Parent1 read: H?
Parent0 read: child0
Parent1 read: H?
Child1 pid 3183 from parent pid 1
Child1: child1
```

I am also confused as to why child1's pid is outputting as 1, as it should be 3181 in this case. Any and all help in greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you are trying to read from `pdes0[0]` and `pdes1[0]` regardless of whether `i` is equal to `0` or `1`.

Also, you are closing both the descriptors in the first run of the loop. When `i` is equal to `1`, the descriptors are no longer valid, the calls to `read` return with failure and you proceed to use the buffers as though they hold valid data.

Here's an updated version of the parent's side of the code.

```
/* parent */
if ( i == 0 )
{
   char inbuf0[10];
   close(pdes0[1]);
   read(pdes0[0], inbuf0, 10);
   printf("Parent0 read: %s\n", inbuf0);
   close(pdes0[0]);
}

if ( i == 1 )
{
   char inbuf1[10];
   close(pdes1[1]);
   read(pdes1[0], inbuf1, 10);
   printf("Parent1 read: %s\n", inbuf1);
   close(pdes1[0]);
}
```

With that change, I get the expected output.

```
Parent pid: 7262
Child0 pid 7263 from parent pid 7262
Child0: child0
Parent0 read: child0
Child1 pid 7264 from parent pid 7262
Child1: child1
Parent1 read: child1
```

---

Also, the checks

```
if(pdes0 < 0)
```

and

```
if(pdes1 < 0)
```

are wrong. In those lines, the arrays decay to `int*` and they will always evaluate to true. Here's what they need to be:

```
int st0 = pipe(pdes0);
int st1 = pipe(pdes1);
if(st0 < 0)
{
   printf("Error creating pipe pdes0\n");
}
if(st1 < 0)
{
   printf("Error creating pipe pdes1\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is helpful!